# POST query from user input on button click

Tags: php, mysql, database, post, input

This is what I'm trying to do. I let the user to input DATEFROM and DATETO. Then when the user click the button, it will execute a query to SELECT * from my table WHERE DATEFROM BETWEEN DATETO. I don't know what's wrong. Please help.

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <?php
        <form method="POST" action="">
        DATE FROM: <input type="date" name="datefrom"> TO: <input type="date" name="dateto"> <input type="submit" value="Extract excel file" name="extract"></input>
        </form>

        $datefrom = "datefrom";
        $dateto = "dateto";

        if(isset($_POST['extract'])){
            mysql_connect("localhost", "root");
            mysql_select_db("sample");

            $myquery = "SELECT * FROM biometrics WHERE date_created BETWEEN '" . $datefrom . "' AND '" . $dateto . "ORDER BY id_biometrics";


            $result = mysql_query($myquery);

            echo "<table border='1'>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Employee Number</th>
                <th>Date Created</th>
                <th>Time Created</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>";

            while($data = mysql_fetch_row($result))
            {
                echo("<tr>
                <td>$data[0]</td>
                <td>$data[1]</td>
                <td>$data[2]</td>
                <td>$data[3]</td>
                <td>$data[4]</td>
                </tr>");
            }

            echo "</table>";

        }

        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have missed a quote(') in query ,try like this

```
if(isset($_POST['extract'])){
        mysql_connect("localhost", "root");
        mysql_select_db("sample");

          $datefrom = $_POST['datefrom'];
          $dateto = $_POST['dateto'];

        $myquery = "SELECT * FROM biometrics WHERE date_created BETWEEN '" . $datefrom . "' AND '" . $dateto . "' ORDER BY id_biometrics";


        $result = mysql_query($myquery);
```

hope this works for you

Comment: IT WORKED!! THANK YOU SO MUCH. Now I have to extract it in csv file. thanks so much again. :D

Answer (score 1):

Why there is no password in this line.

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "root");
```

Hope the date_created column is in Date or Datetime format. It must not be a int or a varchar or any other thing.

And also add the quotes before ORDER BY.

```
   $myquery = "SELECT * FROM biometrics WHERE date_created BETWEEN '" . $datefrom . "' AND '" . $dateto . "' ORDER BY id_biometrics";
```

Comment: because I don't have password in myphpadmin. about the date or datetime, I'll go check it out. thanks. :D

Comment: If you dont have a passowrd, just have it as null value. It must be mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");

Answer (score 0):

You missed `'`, it should be

```
"SELECT * 
       FROM biometrics 
       WHERE date_created 
       BETWEEN '" . $datefrom . "' AND '" . $dateto . "' ORDER BY id_biometrics";
                                                       ^
                                                       ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, You need add space BEFORE `ORDER BY`

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");

$myquery = "SELECT * FROM biometrics WHERE date_created BETWEEN ('" . $datefrom . "' AND '" . $dateto . "') ORDER BY id_biometrics";
```